# Suitable QImage format

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

I'm having a one Channel image, and want to display it in a QImage

```
IplImage *img=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

Knowing that When converting from an IplImage* to QImage, I did what is follow:

```
uchar* img_d=(uchar*) img->imageData;
    QImage img_direction((uchar*)img_d, img->width, img->height, QImage::Format_Mono);
```

I'm not pretty sure about the Mono format that I have set, even the displayed QImage would be scrambled!

What would be the suitable QImage format for the case of a B&W image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt's Mono format is 1-bit per pixel.

The only 8-bit format is `QImage::Format_Indexed8`, so you'll need to create a color table with the 256 grays and pass it to [QImage::setColorTable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setColorTable).

The table could be filled like this:

```
QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
for(int i=0; i<256; ++i)
   colorTable << qRgb(i,i,i);
```

Comment: This was very helpful.  I upvoted... dunno about the downvote.